# Select string based on its index in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, html, indexing

How do I get the p tag to display only the text in the range of the specified index (which is the special character ('?') here.)... If there's a way to do it inversely (in cases where I might have multiple similar special characters concatenated (ex: Hello...) and I want to select the last one) like the python "rindex" method, I'd like to know that too.

```
**JavaScript**
function check(){
var s = document.getElementById("text").innerHTML;
var c;
c = s.substring(0,  s.indexOf('?'));
}

**HTML**
<button id="check" type="submit" onclick="check()">Check</button>
<p id="text"> Hello, what's up with you? Haven't seen you in ages!</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use lastIndexOf()

```
let c = s.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf('?'));
```

Documention:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf